# outputting html in javascript

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have been upgrading legacy pages to load data with AJAX.

The ajax call returns an object with custom properties

```
{ 
  item: {
    id: 1,
    name: 2,
   ...
  }
}
```

In my AJAX call I am building the elements

```
$.post("./url/returns-json", query, function(data) {
   var response = JSON.parse(data);
   $.each(response , function(i, v){
       var r = '<div class="style-this"><p>';
       var r += v.name;
       var r += '</p></div>';
       $("item-wrap").append(r);
   });
});
```

is there another way to wrap json response in HTML for display.

This method can get very untidy when building big HTML elements

Comment: You should probably use a templating language like [jade](http://jade-lang.com/). You can compile your templates to be called with data, and it will save you from corner cases, escaping entities, etc.

Comment: You are using jQuery and assemble the HTML code manually? Oh dear, that's what jQuery is for! `$('<div class="style-this">').append($('<p>').text(v.name));`

Comment: @JonSurrell Any other libs that are plug and play and dont require installing node, npm etc - Something that I can drop in individual files as opposed to system wide.

Comment: I would recommend doing only a single `append` outside the loop.  Appending to the DOM is very intensive operation and should be done as few times as possible.

Comment: @still_learning Good point. however, even using the proper methods to build the html, when outputting large html blocks.

Comment: What are you using on the server side to assemble HTML? If you're already using templating there, you can assemble the HTML on the server and return it to your AJAX call.

Comment: Jade doesn't require node or npm to run, just to build. The templates run in the browser. Your templates can be compiled to functions as part of a build step, then you include that compiled code in your pages. (along with the [jade runtime](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/raw/master/runtime.js).

Comment: You can also find numerous jQuery templating languages by doing a simple Google search...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) as a templating engine?

Comment: That is similar to what I was looking for - something I can use right away before implementing a full fledged templating system.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach might be this:

```
$('#item-wrap').append(
  $('<div>').addClass('style-this').append(
    $('<p>').text(v.name)
  )
);
```

In my opinion, jQuery is actually great to dynamically build HTML structures. By indenting the code, the structure is visible very well and utility functions such as `text` allow you to insert content safely (see XSS).

*I assumed `item-wrap` was actually an element identifier, not a tag name. This does not affect my answer.*

Comment: Good point - ill try that - I was hoping to get find a lib that can act like a plug and play template ( not unlike jade ) that I could use on select pages

Answer (score 0):

You can and probably should use [jQuery DOM Manipulation Methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/). This can seem longer and maybe even more tedious when you just want to add a couple of elements, but when you do detailed and extensive dom manipulation, using jQuery methods make it much more sustainable and easy to read.

```
$.each(response, function(i, v) {
  var div = jQuery("<div>").addClass("style-this"),
    p = jQuery("<p>").text(v.name);
  p.appendTo(div);
  div.appendTo($("item-wrap"));
});
```

While you can shorten this by adding appends to each other, when you adding any more than two or three elements, and if they have additional manipulation done on them, chaining them makes it very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use something similar to this:

```
var template='<div class="style-this"><p>{{name}}</p></div>',
    results=[];
$.each(response , function(i, v){
  results.push(template.replace('{{name}}',v.name));
});
$("item-wrap").append(results.join(''));
```

Another way would be to create a simple "template" function you can pass an object to:

```
function format(template, map) {
  return template.replace(/{([a-z_]+[a-z0-9_]*)}/gi, function(tag, name) {
    return map[name] ? map[name]  : '';
  });
}

// example
alert(format('test {ex} or {deus} {blank}', {'ex' : 'me', 'deus' : 'yourself'}));
```